# Trying to split long string and use its data for a list

Tags: java, string

I have this

```
 String t=  "Mark.Labinson/11051985/Chicago Michael.Louis/25081972/NewYork Gabriel.Vitton/05051988/SanDiego"
```

I've created a new java class Users with the some empty fields like first_name, last_name etc.
I'm trying to use the data from the string t to fill up those empty fields in class Users, because after that, those fields should instantiated in a list..

To be more clear, I'm trying to make the output look like this :

```
 Name: Mark
 Surname: Labinson
 Birthday: 11 may 1985
 Birthplace : Chicago
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Use the `split` method on String.

Comment: Please describe *specific* problem you are facing. What is stopping you from continuing/finishing writing your code? You probably already seen `split` method which should solve your problem. Do you have some trouble with using it which is not explained/clear after reading documentation of that method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also do like this:

> UsersTest class

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class UsersTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        String record =  "Mark.Labinson/11051985/Chicago Michael.Louis/25081972/NewYork Gabriel.Vitton/05051988/SanDiego";
        String[] users = record.split("\\s+");

        List<User> userList = new ArrayList<User>();
        for(String user : users) {
            userList.add(new User(user.split("\\/|\\.")));
        }
        System.out.println("userList : "+ userList);
    }
}
```

> User class

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

public class User {

    private SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy");
    private SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy");
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String birthDate;
    private String birthPlace;

    public User(String[] user) throws ParseException {
        this(user[0], user[1], user[2], user[3]);
    }

    public User(String firstName, String lastName, String birthDate, String birthPlace) throws ParseException {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.birthDate = outputFormat.format(inputFormat.parse(birthDate));
        this.birthPlace = birthPlace;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public String getBirthDate() {
        return birthDate;
    }

    public String getBirthPlace() {
        return birthPlace;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User [firstName=" + firstName + ", lastName=" + lastName
                + ", birthDate=" + birthDate + ", birthPlace=" + birthPlace
                + "]\n";
    }
}
```

> Output:

```
userList : [User [firstName=Mark, lastName=Labinson, birthDate=11 May 1985, birthPlace=Chicago]
, User [firstName=Michael, lastName=Louis, birthDate=25 Aug 1972, birthPlace=NewYork]
, User [firstName=Gabriel, lastName=Vitton, birthDate=05 May 1988, birthPlace=SanDiego]
]
```

Comment: Why do you escape `/` in split?

Comment: I've made it! I was very close,but again,it was giving me error,something like ''can't parse it on index 8''.. Thank you all,appreciate that!

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this to split the String seperate with `/` ,`space` and `.`:

```
String t = "Mark.Labinson/11051985/Chicago Michael.Louis/25081972/NewYork Gabriel.Vitton/05051988/SanDiego";
List<String> items = Arrays.asList(t.split("(/|\\.|\\s)+"));
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy");
for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i += 4) {
    System.out.println("Name: " + items.get(i));
    System.out.println("Surname: " + items.get(i + 1));
    try {
        System.out.println("Birthday: " + format.parse(items.get(i + 2)));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }  
    System.out.println("Birthplace: " + items.get(i + 3));
    System.out.println();
}
```

Output:

> Name: Mark
>   Surname: Labinson
>   Birthday: Sat May 11 00:00:00 CEST 1985
>   Birthplace: Chicago
>
> Name: Michael
>   Surname: Louis
>   Birthday: Fri Aug 25 00:00:00 CET 1972
>   Birthplace: NewYork
>
> Name: Gabriel
>   Surname: Vitton
>   Birthday: Thu May 05 00:00:00 CEST 1988
>   Birthplace: SanDiego

Comment: @ana I tested this solution, what error do you have?

Answer (score 1):

Try with split.

```
String t=  "Mark.Labinson/11051985/Chicago Michael.Louis/25081972/NewYork Gabriel.Vitton/05051988/SanDiego";

   String[] tArray = t.split("\\/|\\.");

        for (int i = 0; i < tArray.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(tArray[i]);
        }
```

Comment: Why do you escape `/` in split?

Answer (score 1):

Use following code

```
public static void main(String[] s) throws ParseException {
    String t=  "Mark.Labinson/11051985/Chicago Michael.Louis/25081972/NewYork Gabriel.Vitton/05051988/SanDiego";

    String[] items = t.split("/");
    String[] nameSurname = items[0].split("\\.");
    String[] places = items[2].split(" ");
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy");
    System.out.println("Name: " + nameSurname[0]); // Name: Mark
    System.out.println("Surname: " + nameSurname[1]); // Surname: Labinson
    System.out.println("Birthday: " + format.parse(items[1])); // Birthday: Sat May 11 00:00:00 CEST 1985
    System.out.println("Birthplace: " + places[0]); // Birthplace: Chicago
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it several ways. You can use regex to break apart the strings or just basic functions that come as part of the String class. Here is an approach using just the string class and a date formatter.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    String t =  "Mark.Labinson/11051985/Chicago Michael.Louis/25081972/NewYork Gabriel.Vitton/05051988/SanDiego";

    String[] userInputs = t.split(" ");

    for(String input : userInputs){
        SimpleDateFormat dateInputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy");
        SimpleDateFormat dateOutputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy");

        String[] fields = input.split("/");
        String firstName = fields[0].substring(0, fields[0].indexOf("."));
        String lastName = fields[0].substring(fields[0].indexOf(".")+1);
        Date birthdate = dateInputFormat.parse(fields[1]);
        String birthplace = fields[2];          

        System.out.println("Name:\t\t" + firstName);
        System.out.println("Surname:\t" + lastName);
        System.out.println("Birthday:\t" + dateOutputFormat.format(birthdate));
        System.out.println("Birthplace:\t" + birthplace + "\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a hashset:

```
/**
* Read a line of text from standard input (the text
* terminal), and return it as a set of words.
*
* @return A set of Strings, where each String is one of the
* words typed by the user
*/
public HashSet<String> getInput()
{
   System.out.print("> "); // print prompt
   String inputLine = reader.nextLine().trim().toLowerCase();
   String[] wordArray = inputLine.split("(\\/|\\.|\\s)+"));
   // add words from array into hashset
   HashSet<String> words = new HashSet<String>();
   for(String word : wordArray) {
      words.add(word);
   }
   return words;
}
```

Comment: Why do you escape `/` in split? This is Java, not JavaScript. `/` has no special meaning here.

Comment: Anyway how does it answer the question? Where OP mentions that she wants hashset which is unordered collection?